# IOS leaks memory when fetching images using photo framework and adding in to NSMutabledictionary

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

My problem is I have already a mutable array of dictionary and I want replace image object already exist in these dictionary, look what I do I am fetching images from library using photokit with asset object and after fetched image I do some drawing and resizing task on image and then take replace this image from existing image in dictionary.When I execute this code the ios memory constantly increases and its recaches to 500MB,I have putted whole code in to @autoreleasepool but bad luck not fixed yet.Please help me out from this.

```
@autoreleasepool
{

    for (int k=0; k<app.SelectedAssetsArray.count; k++)
    {

          PHAsset *asset=(PHAsset *)app.AssetsArray[k];

          BOOL ishave=NO;
          NSString *url=asset.localIdentifier;
          NSInteger count=0;
          for (int i=0; i<[app.arrayOfEditedImageInfo count]; i++)
          {
              NSString *url2=[[app.arrayOfEditedImageInfo objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"url"];
              if ([url isEqualToString:url2])
              {

                  ishave=YES;
                  count=i;
                  break;
              }
          }

          if (ishave)
          {
              PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
              options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
              options.synchronous = YES;
              options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
              options.progressHandler = ^(double progress, NSError *error, BOOL *stop, NSDictionary *info)
              {

              };


              PHCachingImageManager*  imageManager = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];
              [imageManager requestImageDataForAsset:(PHAsset *)app.AssetsArray[k]
                                             options:options
                                       resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info)
               {
                   UIImage *image =[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

                   NSArray *currentText=[[app.arrayOfEditedImageInfo objectAtIndex:count] valueForKey:@"labels"];
                   UIImage *currentimg=image;
                   if (currentText.count>0)
                   {
                       for (int l=0; l<[currentText count]; l++)
                       {
                           IQLabelView *label=[currentText objectAtIndex:l];
                           UITextField *texffld2=[[ label subviews]objectAtIndex:0];
                           UIImage *  renderingImg=[self drawText:texffld2.text inImage:currentimg atPoint:CGPointMake(label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.origin.y) withLabel:label];
                           currentimg=[self normalizedImage:renderingImg size:string];
                           // currentimg=renderingImg;
                       }  
                   }

                   NSMutableDictionary *dict2=[app.arrayOfEditedImageInfo  objectAtIndex:count];
                   NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
                   [dict setObject:currentimg forKey:@"thumbImage"];
                   [dict setObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(160, 204)] forKey:@"centerPoints"];
                   [dict setObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)] forKey:@"contentOffsets"];
                   [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1] forKey:@"scales"];

                      [dict setValue:[dict2 valueForKey:@"labels"] forKey:@"labels"];


                   [dict setValue:[dict2 valueForKey:@"arrayForLabelDetails"] forKey:@"arrayForLabelDetails"];
                   [dict setValue:asset.localIdentifier forKey:@"url"];

                     [app.arrayOfEditedImageInfo replaceObjectAtIndex:count withObject:dict];


               }];

    }
}
```

Comment: Analyse your project by shift+command+B.It will identify memory leaks. It will help you to release any unnecessary objects.

Comment: Thats not worked for me.